# Django 1.7 registration app taking default templates cannot overide? How to override

Tags: python, django, django-1.7

```
NoReverseMatch at /accounts/password/reset/

Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'uidb64': 'Ng', u'token': u'42o-0f6e33b817dc01d94f48'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['accounts/password/reset/$']

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://0.0.0.0:8000/accounts/password/reset/
Django Version:     1.7.2
Exception Type:     NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    

Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'uidb64': 'Ng', u'token': u'42o-0f6e33b817dc01d94f48'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['accounts/password/reset/$']

Exception Location:     /home/mahiti/dj1.7/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 468
Python Executable:  /home/mahiti/dj1.7/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.6
Python Path:    

['/home/mahiti/GitProjects/IOT',
 '/home/mahiti/dj1.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/mahiti/dj1.7/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/mahiti/dj1.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/mahiti/dj1.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/mahiti/dj1.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/mahiti/dj1.7/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']

Server time:    Wed, 17 Jun 2015 11:35:32 +0000



Error during template rendering

In template /home/mahiti/dj1.7/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration/password_reset_email.html, error at line 6


Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'uidb64': 'Ng', u'token': u'42o-0f6e33b817dc01d94f48'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['accounts/password/reset/$']
1   {% load i18n %}{% autoescape off %}
2   {% blocktrans %}You're receiving this email because you requested a password reset for your user account at {{ site_name }}.{% endblocktrans %}
3   
4   {% trans "Please go to the following page and choose a new password:" %}
5   {% block reset_link %}
6   {{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
7   {% endblock %}
8   {% trans "Your username, in case you've forgotten:" %} {{ user.get_username }}
9   
10  {% trans "Thanks for using our site!" %}
11  
12  {% blocktrans %}The {{ site_name }} team{% endblocktrans %}
13  
14  {% endautoescape %}
15
```

The path of Error during template rendering show the python path but the app is with my project folder

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is with your `urls.py` not your templates.

Comment: Yes it was with my templates . Previously i added templates folder with registration (registration/templates/registartion)app but finally i removed it from the app and then pasted that folder to template/registration global template folder